# What is the correct url for checking out AutoMapper from googlecode?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, svn, automapper

I am referring to this project by Jimmy Bogard: http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper

The code repository site is: http://code.google.com/p/automapperhome/source/checkout

The instructed checkout command is: 
svn checkout http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ automapperhome-read-only

This does not work.

I have tried SlikSVN, Tortoise SVN, QSVN, and possibly others that I've forgotten about.

Client: Tortoise SVN

Url: svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ automapperhome-read-only

result

Checkout 'svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ automapperhome-read-only' into 'C:\Development\MVC\automapper'
Can't connect to host 'automapperhome.googlecode.com': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

---

Client: SlikSVN

Command:

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn checkout http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ automapperhome-read-only c:development\automapper

Result:

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': 200 OK (http://automapperhome.googlecode.com)

Command:

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn checkout svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ automapperhome-read-only c:development\automapper

Result:

svn: Can't connect to host 'automapperhome.googlecode.com': A connection attempt
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

---

I'm at a loss. Is there a default port I need to open on my router for this to work. I'm only behind my router's firewall. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

Updated with additional commands attempted for sliksvn:

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn checkout svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ c:development\automapper

svn: Can't connect to host 'automapperhome.googlecode.com': A connection attempt
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn checkout svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

svn: Can't connect to host 'automapperhome.googlecode.com': A connection attempt
 failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
 or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn checkout svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/automapperhome-read-only  c:development\automapper

svn: Can't connect to host 'automapperhome.googlecode.com': A connection attempt
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

*************UPDATE 3********************
Odd. I run the simple checkout command on Qsvn at work and it pulls everything in just fine. Something is definitely wrong on my home machine's setup, but I'm not sure what. I'll look into utilizing Fiddler to examine what's going on. Thanks for your help guys. I know this has probably frustrated you as much as it has me. Nothing irks worse than things not working when they should, but I'm sure there's some oddity on my end that's doing this.

Comment: Try from different computer. Maybe your network configuration affects requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you assume that the repository URL is `http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ automapperhome-read-only`. The correct URL is `http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`. The `automapperhome-read-only` part in the SVN checkout command is the target directory, not part of the URL.

**Update:** Your other mistake is that you are using the `SVN://` protocol for the checkout URL. You should be using the `HTTP://` protocol. The only attempt you show in your question with the `HTTP://` protocol is the first SlikSVN one, where you specify too many options; all other attempts use `SVN://`. Here's the (partial) output from SlikSVN on my machine:

```
C:\Users\francip\Desktop\Projects>svn checkout svn://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ something
svn: Can't connect to host 'automapperhome.googlecode.com': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, o
r established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

C:\Users\francip\Desktop\Projects>svn checkout http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ something
A    something\tools
A    something\tools\subversion
A    something\tools\subversion\ssleay32.dll
A    something\tools\subversion\license
```

The first command uses `SVN://` and gets the same error that you get. The second one uses the correct `HTTP://` and successfully checks out the source.

**Update 2:** You have to specify the target directory at the end of the checkout command. I was looking at the example command in your question and your comments and the only places I saw a target directory, it was in the form of `c:development\automapper` - a relative directory to the current working directory, which in your examples seems to be `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin` - and this one usually is read-only, unless you are running as an administrator.

If that turns out not to be the problem either, I would suggest to remove all current outputs from your question, run `svn checkout http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\automapper` and copy the command and the output verbatim from the console in the question. Baring more details, it's unlikely we will be able to help you further.

In any case, it seems unlikely that the problem is with your network configuration. The URL uses the standard HTTP protocol over port 80 and SVN is returning to you 200 OK, which indicates it's able to connect to the server. Whatever is going wrong is on the local side. Still, you could verify this by running [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/dl/Fiddler2BetaSetup.exe) and trying again.

Comment: Updated question to show additional attempted commands. These still did not work.

Comment: Running the command: C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn checkout h t t p ://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ results in :
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': 200 OK (http://automapperhome.googlecode.com) . 

I tried it with and without a directory location at the end of the command. Same result for both. Is there a port I need to unblock on my router?

I had to space the h t t p so stackoverflow would stop hiding it on my comment. That is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

(Since you are using TortoiseSVN), this works for me:

- create a local folder, where you want to have the automapper source-code
- right-click the new folder, select `SVN Checkout...`
- enter the URL `http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`
- click OK

Your error was to include the `automapperhome-read-only` part in the URL (at least when using TortoiseSVN).

Comment: Doing this results in: 

OPTIONS of 'http://automapperhome.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': 200 OK (http://automapperhome.googlecode.com)