# error fetching source code from http://fluorinefx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ using svn 1.6.6 on windows

Tags: windows, svn, google-code

I am trying to get the source code for FluorineFX silverlight to see if I can update it to run with silverlight 5. When I enter the command

```
svn checkout http://fluorinefx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ fluorinefx-read-only
```

svn responds with the following and does not download anything:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://fluorinefx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': 200 OK (http://fluorinefx.googlecode.com)
```

I have searched and most of the answers are change something on the server, which I obviously can't do.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I am running windows 7 and svn 1.6.6 (which I got from [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=11151&expandFolder=11151&folderID=91)) and trying to get [this](http://code.google.com/p/fluorinefx/source/checkout)

Comment: try https instead of http. If it's an issue with some proxy on your end, using https might help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same command on my end with the same SVN version but I didnt face the issue. I think the issue at your end has to do with proxy / network / authentication things.

Read these and experiment out:

[What is the correct url for checking out AutoMapper from googlecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397533/what-is-the-correct-url-for-checking-out-automapper-from-googlecode)

[An SVN error (200 OK) when checking out from my online repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo)